# Installing xorg-x11-devel package in SLES 11 SP2

Tags: linux, xorg, imagemagick, packages, suse

I am using `Imagemagick(6.4.3.6-7.18.x86_64)` in `SLES11 SP2`

Using it like bellow..

> import -window $wid $jpg

and getting this ***error***

> import: DelegateLibrarySupportNotBuiltIn `' (X11) @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/1303.

This [LINK](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=14055) ***suggests to install the X11 `development package.***

I search for the **package**(`zypper se xorg-x11-devel`) and it's available but when i try to install that getting this message..

> zypper in xorg-x11-devel
>
> Loading repository data...
>
> Reading installed packages...
>
> Resolving package dependencies...
>
> Problem: nothing provides libuuid1 = 1.41.1 needed by libuuid-devel-1.41.1-13.9.x86_64
>
> Solution 1: do not install xorg-x11-devel-7.4-8.18.x86_64
>
> Solution 2: break libuuid-devel by ignoring some of its dependencies
>
> Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c): c

Checked for the `libuuid1` package and this one is already installed on my system.

> zypper info libuuid1
>
> Loading repository data...
>
> Reading installed packages...
>
> Information for package libuuid1:
>
> Repository: SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-11-SP2 11.2.2-1.234
>
> Name: libuuid1
>
> Version: 2.19.1-6.29.3

Now what should be my next step, remove the current `version(2.19.1-6.29.3)` of `libuuid1`  and back to the mentioned older version `libuuid1 = 1.41.1`?

If i do so what problems i might face?

or any other idea/suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded the `libuuid-devel` package from

`http://suse.curingapneus.com.br/SLES-11-SP2-SDK-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1/suse/x86_64/`

After installing this version **(libuuid-devel-2.19.1-6.29.3.x86_64)**

**xorg-x11-devel** package was installed.

**Note:**

> libuuid is used by many things like udev, devmpper, etc so rolling it
>   back probably not a best idea.